# Show with a group of people, fighting evil people from Dark Dimension

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching a (possibly Japanese) TV (live action) show some 10 years ago or so.

In it a group of people came together (as the series progressed) and faught evil people coming from so called "Dark Dimension".

The show started from one guy, and progressively 4 more people joined in as the show progressed. Each person represented a particular element like lightning or fire.

Also when any bad guy will come, it appeared that he/she disturbed the electric field around themself.

I'm not completely sure about this point, but as much as I remember, when they used to fight, they would teleport to another dimension and they would fight with tops (like those in *Beyblade franchise*) and some (dragon-like spirits) (I guess) would represent them and their tops.)

Edit: There is one more detail, all the bad guys would wear shiny black clothes, like black jackets etc. They had a cold, quiet, yet sinister look on their face. 
And as I mentioned, everytime they would appear, they disturbed the electric field around them (I'm mentioning this fact because in the show, the appearance of the evil guy would always accompany electric sparks)

Edit: There were a total of 5 protagonists in the show, each one joined the team when others were incapable of fighting a new bad guy.

Edit: The heroes seemed to have a wooden box or something in which they would keep their tops (or crystals). Also this box would help them to find remaining tops (or crystals). Each time they would defeat a bad guy, a new hint would appear to them about another type of top (or crystal).

Edit: At the end of the show, all of them battle against the last evil guy and after his defeat, The 'darkness' in dark dimension disappears and there is 'Light' all over there.

I want to know what was the name of that TV show.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Just to clear out some possibilities, were the protagonists clad in full body suits or armor like the Power Rangers? And did they drive vehicles like motorcycles?

Comment: The *Kamen Rider* series had enemies from the "Dark Dimension", the various series tended to start with a single protagonist and then accumulate more, and they tended to follow individual themes (albeit more animal-based). Lastly, as with the *touketsu* series, sparks were a very common effect being used for people appearing. That said, they generally fought directly rather than summoning creatures.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Nope they not had any body suits as such like power rangers. Neither they drove any vehicles as such.

Comment: That's fair. Do you remember whether they wore regular clothes or uniforms (possibly color-coordinated to their elements)?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'm sorry, I am not completely sure about it. The only thing I remember about clothing is as I mentioned, the bad guys wore shiny black clothes.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you might be looking for *[Bakugan: Battle Planet](https://bakugan.fandom.com/wiki/Bakugan:_Battle_Planet)*. It focuses on Dan Kouzo as the main character, and gradually introduces the rest of his friends, the "Awesome Ones" into the fight. They are associated with [Attributes/Factions](https://bakugan.fandom.com/wiki/Attribute) of fire, water, wind, earth, light, and darkness, and they fight creatures and characters from the [Doom Dimension](https://bakugan.fandom.com/wiki/Doom_Dimension) using balls that unroll into quasi-mechanical creatures.

### First Episode courtesy of Cartoon Network

Comment: But in Bakugan they throw tiny balls that transform into various creatures, not tops. There is a series of shows called Beyblade where they do use tops.

Comment: @FuzzyBoot thanks for your efforts. But the show which I am talking about was a live action show.

Comment: @user1170874 Are you sure it is live action? There are lots of sentai, but I have never heard of any with a theme of toy tops.

Comment: @KCWong Yup it was live action, but as I mentioned I'm not really sure tops were a part of it or not

Answer (score 0):

Might this be *[Choukou Senshi Changerion](https://tokusatsunetwork.com/2021/09/review-choukou-senshi-changerion/)*, aka *Changérion*?

[image]

> ***Changerion*** follows the story of Suzumura Akira, a private detective played by Takashi Hagino. After getting into a car crash with a SAIDOC truck carrying a mysterious crystal, Akira is accidentally bestowed the power to transform into Changerion. Their original plans for the crystal ruined, the Darkzeid-fighting organisation SAIDOC must instead rely on Akira to fight for them. Darkzeid are monsters that came to Earth from the Dark Dimension, and feed upon Larm (human life energy). This would be a fair setup for your average tokusatsu show – except that Akira has absolutely no intention of being an average tokusatsu hero.

Many of the bad guys did tend toward black shiny costumes:

[image] [image]

Not matching is that it's largely the single protagonist in fights aided by [robots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyOeBXBO_q4), there are no crystal tops as far as I can tell, and most fights seem to happen on Earth.